# Can't send document to PSPad

Tags: windows

I have installed PSPad as a texteditor on my system. The problem is when I right click a document it does not give me the option to send the document to PSPad. Is there under Windows 7 any way that I could tell the OS to add PSPad to this list of applications where documents could be sent to?

Comment: You may want to look on SuperUser for this type of question. http://superuser.com/questions/139968/how-to-add-an-item-to-my-send-to-context-menu

Answer (score 1):

Go to `[Settings]->[Program Settings...]->[System integration]`

Select `[Register in System context menu]` and one or all of the other checkboxes under this.

You may need a system restart after this for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

- Run PSPad as Adminstrator (right click on PSPad icon in start menu)
- Uncheck **Register in System context menu** in Menu | Settings | Program Settings... |  System Integration
- Apply
- Check again
- OK

That's it. You only need to do it once when running PSPad as Adminstrator.